# ionic want e.detail.scrollBottom

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

```js
.directive('scrollWatch', function($rootScope) {
        return function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var start = 0;
            var threshold = 150;

            elem.bind('scroll', function(e) {
                if(e.detail.scrollTop - start > threshold) {
                    $rootScope.slideHeader = true;
                } else {
                    $rootScope.slideHeader = false;
                }
                console.log('e'+ e.detail.scrollTop);
                if ($rootScope.slideHeaderPrevious  >= e.detail.scrollTop - start) {
                    $rootScope.slideHeader = false;
                }
                console.log($rootScope.slideHeader);
                $rootScope.slideHeaderPrevious = e.detail.scrollTop - start;
                $rootScope.$apply();
            });
        };
    })
```

This give me e.detail.scrollTop
But I want e.detail.scrollBottom. I cannot get about this. 
help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple! basic formula for scrollbottom is

`$(document).height() - $(#element).scrollTop() - $(#element).height();`

since i do not have your entire code i can not give exact solution. But with some trail you can get it. Just simply follow the formula.

that is

> document height - current element position - current element window
>   height

and your code will be like this.

```js
.directive('scrollWatch', function($rootScope) {
        return function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var start = 0;
            var threshold = 150;

            elem.bind('scroll', function(e) {
                if(e.detail.scrollTop - start > threshold) {
                    $rootScope.slideHeader = true;
                } else {
                    $rootScope.slideHeader = false;
                }
                console.log('e'+ e.detail.scrollTop);
                if ($rootScope.slideHeaderPrevious  >= e.detail.scrollTop - start) {
                    $rootScope.slideHeader = false;
                }
                console.log($rootScope.slideHeader);
                $rootScope.slideHeaderPrevious = $(document).height()-e.detail.scrollTop - e.detail.height();
                $rootScope.$apply();
            });
        };
    })
```